'Polarization' of waves in crystal lattice
The vibrations in crystal are modelled as sound waves in debye model of specific heat. The density of states function for these vibrational modes is multiplied by 3 because of allegedly 3 'polarization' of sound waves.Please give more insight on this. I can't understand why it is multiplied by 3 and the word polarization here.

In air you have only one type, consisting of alternating compressions and rarefactions of the air. The movement of the air molecules are in that case back  and forth in the direction of the wave propagation, we call that a longitudinal wave. In solids you can in addition have transverse waves, see for instance this picture on Researchgate.
The transverse waves can have two polarizations, in directions perpendicular to the wave propagation. Together with the longitudinal wave that makes three.

An addition: There can actually be more than three modes of waves in a crystal lattice.
If the primitive unit cell has more than one atom then there are so called "optical" modes. (Although they don't contribute to the low temperature heat capacity, as they are "gapped" – meaning that they have a non-zero frequency for all wave vectors.)
The three ungapped modes are called the acoustic modes and can be associated with "normal" sound waves, where the crystal deforms uniformly (and the atoms within a unit cell move together). The optical modes, on the other hand, correspond, roughly, to the different atoms in the unit cell oscillating against each other.
In general, if there are $k$ atoms in the primitive unit cell, then there are 3k branches of lattice waves (three of which are "acoustic" while the others are "optic").
Wikipedia has a quite thorough discussion of the matter.
